# Spring bean without both class attribute and abstract=true

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, abstract-class

I am working on an old and large code base with definition like this:

```
<bean id="foo" class="com.mycompany.Foo" abstract="true">
  ...
</bean>

<bean id="bar" parent="foo">
  <constructor-arg name="components">
    <list>
      <bean parent="component1">...</bean>
      <bean parent="component2">...</bean>
    </list>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

The `bar` bean doesn't specify a class nor it is abstract. I can't find any beans using `bar` as a parent either.

This seems to violate the documentation

> If the parent definition does not specify a class, explicitly marking
> the parent bean definition as abstract is required
> (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html)

Can someone please explain what this is? The codebase builds and works.